# Android Magnetic Field Sensor: Measure how much time that passes until value changes from pos -> neg (or vice verca)

Tags: java, android

Using Android phones Magnetic Field sensor I am able to get a value depending on Z-Rotation. So if Z-Rotation is a positive value, so will this value (x) be.

```
private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {}
};
```

Here is how I picture it:
[image: Phone angle]

I would like to measure how much time that passes while value (x) is positive or negative.

**For example:**

1. x stays between 0 - 2.5 for 1 second. (positive value)
2. x changes (and stays) between -3.2 - 0 for 1 second. (negative value)
3. x changes (and stays) between 0 - 4.0 for 1 second. (positive value)

*Results:*

positive_value_time = 2 seconds

negative_value_time = 1 seconds

How would I go about and implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this on a real device, but the following should work. This always keeps track of the previous event and then determines the amount of time spent between those events while x was negative or positive. Then it adjusts `negativeTime` and `positiveTime` accordingly.

```java
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;

public class SensorMonitor implements SensorEventListener {
    SensorEvent e0;
    SensorEvent e1;
    
    long positiveTime;  // positive value time in nanoseconds
    long negativeTime;  // negative value time in nanoseconds

    SensorMonitor() {
        this.e0 = null;
        this.e1 = null;
        
        this.positiveTime = 0;
        this.negativeTime = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (this.e0 == null) {
            this.e0 = sensorEvent;
            return;
        }
        this.e1 = sensorEvent;
        
        float x0 = this.e0.values[0];
        float x1 = this.e1.values[0];
        float dx = Math.abs(x1 - x0);
        
        long t0 = this.e0.timestamp;
        long t1 = this.e1.timestamp;
        long dt = t1 - t0;
        
        if (x0 <= 0 && x1 <= 0) {
            this.negativeTime += dt;
        } else if (x0 >= 0 && x1 >= 0) {
            this.positiveTime += dt;
        } else if (x0 <= 0 && x1 >= 0){
            float tn = dt/dx * Math.abs(x0);
            float tp = dt/dx * x1;
            
            this.positiveTime += tp;
            this.negativeTime += tn;
        } else {
            float tn = dt/dx * Math.abs(x1);
            float tp = dt/dx * x0;
            
            this.positiveTime += tp;
            this.negativeTime += tn;
        }
        
        this.e0 = this.e1;
    }
    
        
    // returns positive time in seconds
    public float getPositiveTime() {
        return (float)this.positiveTime / (float)Math.pow(10,9);
    }
    // returns negative time in seconds
    public float getNegativeTime() {
        return (float)this.negativeTime / (float)Math.pow(10,9);
    }
}
```